# Imread() function in python to get the Red, Green and Blue colours.

Tags: python, bitmap, bmp

I am trying to use the imread() to get these colours for a 1400x1400 bmp picture. When i print the imread result I get an integer array with 1400x1400 numbers. Shouldn't there be 5 numbers corresponding to R.G.B.A.X
as shown in here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
from scipy import *
tally=0
#Read in the image
img = imread('M10.bmp',flatten=False)
print len(img[0])  #elements of first array element
print len(img)     #elements of array
print img,         #see what the array looks like
for line in img:
    for ch in line:
        print ch

print tally       #amount of numbers
print len(img[0])*len(img)   #amount of spaces in arrays (to check)
```

Comment: Hi, the imread function works fine for me. I get an array which contains 3 other arrays: r,g,b=img[:,:,0],img[:,:,1],img[:,:,2]. Maybe your bitmap is saved only as monochrome image. There are different ways of saving bmp files and only the most elaborate one has the 5 channels you speak off.

Comment: The usual bitmap saves 4 bytes. Maybe they are represented as numbers when using `imread`. What numbers du you have?

Comment: Hey guys, I think its because an 8 bit bitmap has one slot for one picture colour in a pixel. When you print out your array there are as many numbers as there are pixels. So I think that there can only be a possible of 256 colours.